# Is there any way to change the Bluetooth profile of device programmatically?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am making an app where I can turn the device into a headset programmatically, I want to use the client device as a headset/speaker. How can I change the Bluetooth profile of my receiver device to HEADSET so that other devices could discover my phone as a headphone and can connect to it.
Is thing possible? If yes, please help me and point it out.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Have facing similar challenge, did you found any solution?